# CQRS Command - DTO

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, dto, clean-architecture

i learning CQRS and DDD for a while. My question is how to manage commands. Specially commands, because commands can be more complex then query. How can i write commands with nested dto's?

Comment: I don't see the relation between a command and a DTO. Could you be more precise on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Manel, let's think we have to create product. and same command we have to create related product type. how can i design my command? it's two different table

Comment: Maybe you should look at how to design an event-sourcing / cqrs system. I don't think stackoverflow is the place to cover such a broad topic.

Comment: To quick resume : command -> can write event(s) -> can do projection(s) in a read database (cqrs). Your projections must contains all datas needed by your frontend views.

Comment: @Manel, no, my question is designing the command. in normal application not cqrs we write nested dto's (product dto keeps product type dto) how can we write command that create product and also creates product type?

Comment: Could you show example of your product dto and product type dto ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is define your Domain Models. CQRS can be applied better when you're using DDD. Don't think about the persistence mechanism for now (eg. your DB). That, surprisingly, will become almost an "implementation detail".

Commands should contain only the bare minimum information needed by the system for performing the operation at hand. For example, let's imagine a "Create Customer" command.
It will expose Name, EMail and the Customer ID. The Command instance **has to be immutable**: once initialized, it cannot be changed.
The Command Handler receives the Command instance, validates it against the business invariants and if anything is fine, persists the data.
Command Handlers **don't return data**, they're "fire and forget".

Usually, with CQRS there are 2 distinct persistence storages, one for the *Write* side and another one for the *Read* side. Focus on your Writes first.

Comment: Where did you read that commands are "Fire and Forget"? Commands are Request-Response model and Events are the ones to be "Fire and forget" since you won't know who is going to consume them.

Comment: @JoãoAntunes in the frequent case of asynchronous execution (eg. a Command handler sending a message to a queue), there is no real need to return a result. The Domain operation will be handled elsewhere, hence the Command handler has no need for a return value. 
Now, there are two more things we can take into account: command validation and transient exceptions. 
Validation should happen before the command execution. A command should ALWAYS be valid when is sent to a handler.
Transient exceptions(eg. network issues) can happen and have to bubble up to a valid exception manager.

Comment: In case of synchronous execution instead, I suppose there might be a value returning some kind of "success/failure" result. But to be honest, it's a very rare situation.

Comment: at an asynchronous execution when you send a Command you can track the progress of that command, if you return the OperationStateId, Operation should track the progress of that command. And you can confirm later if that command was executed or not with success, and handle errors properly.